# Kafka consumer-client is not registering offset of consumer group on zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to create multiple consumers with different *consumer groups* to a kafka topic using **kafka-clients v.0.10.2.1**. Although I'm not able to retrieve the last offset commited by a consumer group.

Currently my Consumer properties looks like this

```
Properties cproperties = new Properties();
    cproperties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupID);
    cproperties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, my-broker));
    cproperties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
    cproperties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    cproperties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, taskDecoder.getClass());
    cproperties.put(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "60000");
```

And without the property Auto-reset-offset I can't consume from the topic, but i can't use this config, I need the consumer group registered on zookeeper.
So, I need to create a consumer group on zookeeper /consumers too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the property `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest` (or `latest`, depending on what are you trying to achieve) in order to avoid throwing an exception when an offset is not found (probably because data is deleted).

You also need to make sure that you manually commit offsets since you've disable auto-commit.

```
cproperties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
```

To do so, you can either use [`commitSync()`](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commitAsync(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetCommitCallback))

> This commits offsets to Kafka. The offsets committed using this API
>   will be used on the first fetch after every rebalance and also on
>   startup. As such, if you need to store offsets in anything other than
>   Kafka, this API should not be used. The committed offset should be the
>   next message your application will consume, i.e.
>   lastProcessedMessageOffset + 1.

or [`commitAsync()`](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commitAsync(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetCommitCallback))

> This commits offsets only to Kafka. The offsets committed using this
>   API will be used on the first fetch after every rebalance and also on
>   startup. As such, if you need to store offsets in anything other than
>   Kafka, this API should not be used.
>
> This is an asynchronous call and will not block. Any errors
>   encountered are either passed to the callback (if provided) or
>   discarded.

Note that if you don't commit offsets an exception will be thrown if `auto.offset.reset` is set to `none`.

> What to do when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current
>   offset does not exist any more on the server (e.g. because that data
>   has been deleted):
>
> **earliest:** automatically reset the offset to the earliest offset
>
> **latest:** automatically reset the offset to the latest offset
>
> **none:** throw exception to the consumer if no previous offset is found for the consumer's group
>
> **anything else:** throw exception to the consumer.

Comment: I'm commiting the offsets, i just can't get the offset i'll try set auto.offset.reset to none and see waht happens.

Comment: If you set it to none an exception will be thrown since -according to what you've said- offsets are not committed.

Comment: I'm not getting an exception, though, with the reset set to *none*  I could restore the topic consummation from the right offset, but  I'm not able to localize where this offset is using zookeeper, is there any other place I could look?

Comment: You mean how to get the current offset?

Comment: No, I wanna know where the current offset is being stored, since i'm getting it.